Easiest possible way to solve a question regarding a probability distribution
I have come across this question from Blitzstein, Introduction to Probability, Exercise 30, p 88.

A family has 3 children, creatively named A,B, and C. Find the probability that A is older than B, given that A is older than C.

I have listed out every possible arrangement and the worked out the solution using the conditional probability formula, which is 2/3.
Is there an easier/more mathematical way to do this? I have come across a few problems like this, and often I get stuck, leading me to list out all possible arrangements before continuing to solve the problem. It feels like I'm cheating myself out of learning the intuition required for probability.

"Is there an easier/more mathematical way to do this?" : No, I don't think so.  Further, I think that your approach represents the problem composer's intent.  The only real shortcut is that of the $~\dfrac{3!}{2}~$ sequences where $~A > C,~$ only one of them has $~B > A > C.~$  So, this leads to $$\frac{(3!/2) - 1}{(3!/2)}.$$

With explicit examples of a discrete set of events like this, there is often no way around writing down the event space and proceeding from there. Also, although it is tedious, it actually helps to build your intuition. Probability is ultimately about event spaces. More complicated machinary is needed when dealing with more complicated event spaces, but it is very good to build your intution with some simple concrete examples of them.
